# How to do Password Reset in Symfony 1.4 ? (Without using a plugin)

Tags: plugins, symfony1, passwords, symfony-1.4, reset

I want to add a *Reset Password* option for my User login module. So I've followed [Askeet Tutorial (symfony 1.0)](http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/12).

But I'm getting errors when I click forgot password it redirect to "Password request Action" with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function input_tag() , submit_tag, form_error()

Why am I getting erros for those keywords? Is that mean those are not compatible with my symfony version (i'm using symfony 1.4, tutorial is for symfony 1.0)

**OR** Can any one suggest me any other way to develop this (without using a plugin) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These keywords are related to the old form system of Symfony 1.0. Since Symfony 1.2, there is no more a FormHelper wich containt all its helper (`input_tag`, `textarea_tag`, etc ..) because they are now called widget (`sfWidgetFormInput`, `sfWidgetFormTextarea`, etc ..).

You should **NOT** follow this tutorial since it's for Symfony 1.0 and you are using Symfony 1.4.

Instead, you can see how sfDoctrineGuardPlugin handle its [reset password system](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/modules/sfGuardForgotPassword) (the link point to the module folder, but take also a look into form and model folders).

Comment: Is There any other options to do it without using sfDoctrinePlugin.

Comment: Well, which ORM are you using?

Comment: So you are obviously using sfDoctrinePlugin. What I want to tell you in my answer is not to take every thing from sfGuard plugin, but get inspired on how they handle it. It use Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine, so you have every thing.

Comment: thanks @j0k. i'll try to do it the way u hv suggest to me . thnks for help.