# How to include  user's username and password to a  password recovery mail  in symfony 1.4?

Tags: email, authentication, symfony1, passwords, recovery

I want to add a "Forgot password" function to my User Login module, for that i have created password Recovery action and when user enter an email system will check whether the mail is exist or not and if its exist it will send mail to user. What i want to know is how to include users current password and username to that mail.

How can i do this ?

Comment: God, **please**, don't add any password into any mails you wanted to send to a customer.

Comment: yes. so then what arethe other options which i can for this in symfony ???

Comment: Like what I said in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825623/how-to-do-password-reset-in-symfony-1-4-without-using-a-plugin): look into sfGuardForgotPassword. You will see that it send an email with a (secure and unique) link. This link invite the customer to create a new password. That's all you have to do.

Comment: @j0k  I  agree  & understand, please delete this question and kindly give me access to ask questions from stackoverflow . Thanks!

Comment: @Wouter J  : I  agree  & understand, please delete this question and kindly give me access to ask questions from stackoverflow . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do this ever, *ever*, **EVER**, you send a password recovery hash, and add a token with a time to live to your DB, then send the hash via email to the user who lost their password.  Do not store passwords in the clear, it violates the clients password security, and should your DB be compromised it would release the username and password combinations to your entire userbase.

Store passwords as:

```
   DB.userTable.setTupple(username,sha1(username+"optionaldelimiter"+password));
```

Retreive passwords as:

```
resetPasswd(username : string, hash : string, newPasswd: string)
{
tup = DB.recoveryTable.fetchTupple(username,hash);
  if( tup != null && tup.expiresAt <= Date.now())
  {
  DB.setPasswd(username,newPasswd);
  }
}
```